# equation implementation and matrix mismatch

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing, implementation, digital

i want to implement simple equations.
Here t[n] is number of samples. Equations i want to implement is

```
S=cos⁡(2*pi*fc*t)  

S1t[n]=cos⁡(2*pi*fc*t[n]+ ϕ(t[n])

    Where ϕ(t[n])= ϕ0(t[n])+∑_(k=0)^n▒ϕ1(t[k])
```

, here summation goes from k = 0 to n

Where ϕ0(t[n]) is random variables with gaussian distribution
Where ϕ0(t[n]) is also random variables with gaussian distribution. this is how i have implemented. please, help me what is the bug. Thanks in advance.

```
 ts = 0.01;
  fs = 1/ts;
  nsamples = 100;
  t = 0:ts:nsamples-ts;
  fc = 50;
  S = cos(2*pi*fc*t);                    %%% equation 7.1 noisless
  sigma = 1/1000;
  phi_sync = sigma * rand(1,nsamples);   %%%% random variable with gaussian distributed

for k = 1: nsamples
phi_acc(k,:) = rand(1,nsamples);       %%%% random variable with gaussian distributed
phi(k, :) = phi_sync + phi_acc(k,:);   %%%% equation 7.11
S1(k,:) = cos(2*pi*fc*t + phi(k,:));
end

    %%%% equation 7.10, signal with noise
  figure, plot(fftshift(abs(fft(S1))));
  return
```

Comment: What is the error? How does the result differ from what you expected?

Comment: error is in matrix mismatch. May be i am applying for loop by wrong method. There is a summation in the second equation ϕ(t[n])= ϕ0(t[n])+∑_(k=0)^n▒ϕ1(t[k]). can you tell me the correct way to apply. I want s1 's length (1,10000) like the lenght of S. so after that may be it will work

Comment: What bout `sum(phi_acc(k,:))`?

Comment: I wanted phi_acc(k,:) to go from 0 to n, in for loop. and this term is in pus with Phi_sync. and after that i have created new signal which is the sum of  S1 = cos(2*pi*fc*t)+(phi_acc(k,:) + phi_sync)

Comment: You are adding a vector of length 100 to a vector of length 10000. That is giving you the error. Once you use `sum` you are reducing the vector to a scalar and you can add it.

Comment: you mean in the loop only?